# Build query with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: c++, printf

Currently I have the following code to build a query:

```
char sqlWhereQuery[NORMAL_SQL_QUERY_BUF_LEN];
    int count = _snprintf_s( sqlWhereQuery,
                           _countof(sqlWhereQuery),
                           _TRUNCATE,
                           " WHERE %s = '%d'", CError::ERR_NUMBER, _errorNum );
```

I need to change it to have several errors
I.e.  `WHERE %s = '%d OR  %s = '%d OR  %s = '%d'", CError::ERR_NUMBER, _errorNum1,CError::ERR_NUMBER, _errorNum2,CError::ERR_NUMBER, _errorNum3`
I want to make      more elegant - not specify all errors,
but save them to array..is there a way?

Comment: Yes. Don't use C char buffers and snprintf! Use std::string and std::stringstream. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @Yakov: You should clarify the question. I.e., what is the hypothetical function signature (a.k.a. API) for your query builder and how are you going to use the created query ?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Frankly that isn’t much better, it’s a glaring SQL injection security hole. Instead, use prepared statements.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The code OP provided uses internal constants rather than unsanitized input, so I don't think this is a security hole. Prepared statements may be better but OP didn't give us the SQL library he's using.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really be using char arrays and C string operations in C++. It is the Wrong Thing To Do. The point of using C++ over C is the features of C++. Use a std::stringstream:

```
std::vector<int> error_nums = { /* ... */ };

std::stringstream ss;
for (auto it = error_nums.begin(); it != error_nums.end(); ++it) {
    ss << " WHERE " << CError::ERR_NUMBER << " = '" << *it << "'";
}
std::string query_string = ss.str();
const char* query_cstr = query_string.cstr(); // if needed
```

Since you're using constants here, this is not a SQL injection vulnerability, but in the more general case where you're using user input this sort of code should really be avoided. Use the prepared statements offered by your SQL library in that case. You may want to use those by default out of habit.

Comment: **This is dangerous advice!** As mentioned, this is a glaring security hole. There’s virtually no acceptable reason to ever concatenate SQL code manually rather than using prepared statements.

Comment: @KonradRudolph As I said, not a SQL injection hole. It uses internal constants, it's essentially a string literal with more steps. I'll add a disclaimer for the more general case though.

Comment: That’s not sufficient reason to avoid best practices that have no drawbacks. Errors creep in. Put differently, the risk/reward ratio is simply *way* too high — so high that this is a no-brainer. Injection vulnerabilities are the *number one vulnerability* worldwide for well over a decade now, they cost the economy **billions**, and it’s often from seemingly innocuous code like this.